# Inserir shortcode de Wordpress em um arquivo .twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, shortcode

Estou atualizando um site que está usando tender com twig, preciso simplesmente colocar um shortcode, mas a solução que tenho não está dando certo, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?
o código twig que tentei foi:

```
<div>{{post.custom_shortcode_field('[wdi_feed id="1"]')}}</div>
```

Mas o resultado é apenas uma div vazia...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei algumas coisas:

```
{% filter shortcodes %}
    [wdi_feed id="1"]
{% endfilter %}
```

ou:

```
{{ function('do_shortcode', '[wdi_feed id="1"]') }}
```

ou, se este shortcode estiver em um campo customizado, é só adicionar o pipe shortcodes:

```
{{ post.NOME_DO_FIELD | shortcodes }}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Resolveu, Obrigado!